# Banning all java.sql package with PMD and XPath

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

So I'm currently writing some PMD custom rules for my code. I'm supposed to ban any use of the java.sql package but I don't know to solve it. I imagine I can just read the package documentation and ban all the functions one by one, but I suppose there is a better option.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for any type or import starting with 'java.sql.' as so:

```
/CompilationUnit/ImportDeclaration/Name[starts-with(@Image, 'java.sql.')]
| //ClassOrInterfaceType[starts-with(@Image, 'java.sql.')]
```

You can read on how to define your own XPath rule [in the docs](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.18.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html#creating-a-new-rule-definition)

Comment: Note that in 7.0.0, the `Name` node will be removed. The recommended 7.0 compatible usage is to use the attribute `@ImportedName` of the `ImportDeclaration`. Eg `//ImportDeclaration[starts-with(@ImportedName, ...)]`